# LPR landscape requests for bizhub printers?

Tags: linux, printing, lpr

Does anyone have any experience with setting up LPR requests to Konica Minolta printers? I have been searching for weeks trying to find the correct syntax to send a request for landscape printing to a Bizhub C227 and C458.

Does anyone have any advice? BTW the request is directly to the printer, not through CUPS.